# Javascript for text highlight tooltip in mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, mobile-browser

I want to open a tooltip beside text selected in a mobile browser (e.g., Chrome in Android). Since text selection in mobile browsers does not trigger mouse events, I cannot use `mouseup` event.

```
document.addEventListener("selectionchange", function(event) {

    var text = window.getSelection().toString();
    var tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip');
    var x = event.clientX; // The problem
    var y = event.clientY; // The Problem
    tooltip.innerHTML = text;
    tooltip.style.top = x + 'px';
    tooltip.style.left = y + 'px';
});
```

The problem is that `ClientX` and `ClientY` do not work with `selectionchange`.

Check the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v90g2qf5/9/).

Comment: You can track the last known `touchstart/touchmove/touchend` positions and use them.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol excellent tip, I will try it.

Comment: I think the issue is that you need to first know what element you are clicking on that has the text inside so possibly first place a mousedown/up event on the container and get the clientX from there? Just a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the [bounding rect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) of the text selection and place the tooltip based on that data. The rect will tell you the width, height, x, y, top, right, bottom, and left of the selection.

```js
document.addEventListener("selectionchange", function(event) {
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  
  if (selection.rangeCount === 0) {
    return;
  }

  const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
  const rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
  const text = selection.toString();
  const tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip');

  tooltip.innerHTML = text;
  tooltip.style.top = rect.bottom + 5 + 'px'; // 5px offset
  tooltip.style.left = rect.x + 5 + 'px';     // 5px offset
  tooltip.style.position = 'absolute';
  tooltip.style.background = 'lightgreen';
});
```

```html
This is some text
<div id="tooltip">
```

Comment: Note that `toString()` is experimental, and may not work on iOS Safari https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection

Answer (score 0):

You can add mouseup event and do that code in mouseup event handler.

```
var tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip');
document.addEventListener("selectionchange", function(event) {
    var text = window.getSelection().toString();
    tooltip.innerHTML = text;
});

document.addEventListener("mouseup", function(event){
    var x = -1000;
    var y = -1000;
    if(tooltip.innerHTML!=""){
        x =event.clientX;
        y = event.clientY;
    }
    tooltip.style.top = x + 'px';
    tooltip.style.left = y + 'px';
});
```

I have tested it on [jsFiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/v90g2qf5/22/) as well.